# Android: Image downloaded but not displayed in imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-imageview, sd-card

I have downloaded image from url to sd card. It is shown as normal thumbnail image in sd card but when i click it to view it a message is shown `Could not load image` also the image is not displayable in imageview. The image was downloaded with the help of Async Task. Now i want to check first if image is displayable or not. If not delete it and redownload it.

Code for downloading the images:

```
      protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
      try{
      String fileName = params[0].substring(params[0].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  URL url = new URL(params[0]);
  HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
  urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                   
  urlConnection.connect();   

  File file = new File(SwipeActivity.filename,fileName);

  FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
  InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream(); 
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int bufferLength = 0;
  while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
  {                 
    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);                
  }             
  fileOutput.close(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return null;
}
```

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: I think this github link will help you not just downloading images but also showing images on UI Part. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: can you post the respective code you are using to download image and how you are setting it to imageview?

Comment: @swapnil this is very helpful. Kindly also guide me how to download them simultaneously.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia i've edited and included code for downloading each image. And am displaying the images when downloaded in viewpager imageview.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking whether the image is displayable in build in Gallery app. Ive had this issue with, as it seemed, usual PNG image, the trick was it wasnt an RGB pic, but the CMYK color format. The output was similar to yours, android doesnt display CMYK images in a straight way